# How to open up the notebook file as JSON content

Tags: jupyter, google-colaboratory

Usually ipynb file is basically a `JSON` file, right?

For `Colab Enterprise` I can not find where the notebook file is. It's not under `/content` for sure.

I see there is a button under `tools` > `Command palette` > `View Notebook JSON`,it works superbly fine, but is there anyway to access to notebook content in json format through `code`?

I look around in [this repo: colabtools](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools), and it guided me here